# How to create UVs for a number of duplicated objects

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I created an object and duplicated it a number of times and arranged them in a specific order but forgot to unwrap the original object .Now I have about fifty of them without UV or texture .Is there any way to unwrap them easily and apply texture? I cannot create UVs for each of them beacause I have made some differences in each of them (like length, width ,etc ) .So is there any way of getting the work done quicker?

Answer (score 3):

You could pick one object as a template and setup the material and texture.

After that select all objects which should get the material settings assigned and add the template as last object to you selected object (must be the active object).

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> Opens the Make Links Popup

[image]

Select Materials, after that open the Popup again and select Transfer UV-Maps.
[image]

- [Video Tutorial on Make Links](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2009/09/11/703/)
- [Documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System)